# Rewriterule with exception for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I use a rewriterule to this:

> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1

How I can do this rewriterule work only if my domain is WWW ou empty? Because I have others subdomains that not use this rule.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
```

before your `RewriteRule`

Comment: ok, its work, but my principal domain now, not work for example.com/page

Comment: @GtOkAi, I updated the code. Can you please explain again? but this time in English please.

Comment: sorry for bad english...

Now, work only in example.com and www.example.com, when a use a dir like www.example.com/dir or www.example.com/dir not work.